# How to decrypt/encrypt data using AES GCM with tag received from APIs in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, aes, aes-gcm

In API response I m getting AES GCM encrypted data with tag and trying to decrypt the same data with tage received from API response using below code, Please help here to decrypt data using AES-GCM with tag value.

```
func aesDecrypt(phrase:String, key: String, iv: String) throws -> String {
    
    if let data: Array<UInt8> = (Data(base64Encoded: phrase)?.bytes)
    {
        let key: Array<UInt8> = (key.data(using: .utf8)?.bytes)!
        let iv: Array<UInt8> = (iv.data(using: .utf8)?.bytes)!
        print("IVVVVVVVV:\(iv)")
        let tag: Array<UInt8> = (self.tagStr.data(using: .utf8)?.bytes)!
        
        let decGCM = GCM(iv: iv, authenticationTag: tag , mode: .detached)
        let decrypted = try AES(key: key, blockMode: decGCM, padding: .noPadding).decrypt(data)
        print("DECRYPTED:\(decrypted)")
        
        let decryptedData = Data(decrypted)
        
        guard let value = String.init(data: decryptedData, encoding: .utf8) else {
            return "error"
        }
        return value
    }
    return ""
}
```

Uses:

```
let decryptData = try self.aesDecrypt(phrase: responseData, key: key, iv: iv)
```

Comment: Decryptions are tailored to encryptions. So post the encryption code or at least complete (non productive) sample data: plaintext, ciphertext, key, nonce/IV, tag.

Comment: The code has a few oddities: E.g. a tag is usually corrupted by a UTF-8 decoding (check if the tag is not rather Base64 or hex encoded); also it's strange that the tag is handled as member variable while ciphertext, key and IV are passed as function parameters; a UTF-8 encoded key and IV are (at least) vulnerabilities,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your time:

I have solved the issue using below code, it is working fine for me. Thank you.

```
func commonEncryptAESGCM(params:[String:Any]) -> (String, String)  {
    
    let jsonStr = arrayToJsonString(from: params)
    print("Array String",jsonStr!)
    
    let iv = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: UserDefautKeys.aesIV) as! String
    let keys = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: UserDefautKeys.aesKey) as! String
    print("IV Key",iv,keys)
    
    let initializationVector: Data = Data(iv.utf8) // Your IV
    let nonce = initializationVector
    
    let key = SymmetricKey(data: keys.data(using: .utf8)!)
    
    // Encrypt
    let sealedData = try! AES.GCM.seal(jsonStr!.data(using: .utf8)!, using: key,
                                       nonce: AES.GCM.Nonce(data: nonce))
    let data = sealedData.ciphertext.base64EncodedString()
    let tag = sealedData.tag.base64EncodedString()
    print("Data: \(data)")
    print("Tag: \(tag)")
    return (data, tag)
}
```

Uses:

```
let result = commonEncryptAESGCM(params: paramStr)
```